# How to download an attachment from Outlook API with PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I want to download an attachment. I have reached to attachment with the request:

`/me/message/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}`

Response is:

```
[_propDict:protected] => Array
        (
            [@odata.context] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('username')/messages('messageId')/attachments/$entity
            [@odata.type] => #microsoft.graph.fileAttachment
            [@odata.mediaContentType] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
            [id] => xxx
            [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2019-11-02T17:50:52Z
            [name] => xxx.xlsx
            [contentType] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
            [size] => 33459
            [isInline] => 
            [contentId] => f_k2hv435z0
            [contentLocation] => 
            [contentBytes] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
                (
                    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #374
                    [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
                    [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
                    [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

There is not `sourceUrl` but `contentBytes`. Can I do that with `contentBtyes` and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `$object->getContentBytes()` should work for you.

UPD: If you want then to download the contents as a file, you could do something similar to this:

```
$fileName = "download.txt";
$contents =  $object->getContentBytes(); // base64_decode() here if needed

header("Content-type: text/plain"); // Or any other format
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
print $contents;
die;
```

Comment: It gives me string.

Comment: so what's in that string? Is that the attachment content that you were looking for?

Comment: It is byte format. But i convert with base64_decode() and i can read some text about file. Example xls or png among converted text. But i can't download as file.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can download as a file

Comment: But I can't do that :)

Comment: Use the code I posted in the answer. 
Be sure to assign proper MIME type in the Content-Type header. Then you can download any file.

Comment: IT worked. But update to: $obgect->getContentBytes();